# Send SMTP email with embedded Google font

Tags: html, css, asp.net, email

I'm trying to send an email from an ASPX C# page.
I want the email font to be from Google fonts.

On server side, I've specified:

```
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Here is the HTML I'm sending.

```
<html>
     <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:400,700&amp;subset=hebrew,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>   
      <body style="font-family:'Rubik';font-size:10pt;color:#4b5659;">
          <center>
              test text
          </center>
     </body>
</html>
```

Still, the email arrives without the specified font (uses default font).

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most email clients are not capable of processing complex CSS. And that includes embedded fonts. That's why email templates should be fairly simple.

See this [Support Guide](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for more detail.

Comment: The support guide you included states that all client support font-family, which is what I'm using. So, I find this answer lacking a solution or explenation

Comment: Yes it supports `font-family`, but only with default fonts installed on the client like Arial, Verdana etc.